# dispatching a reducer action resets form values react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, webforms, use-form

I have forgot password page which obviously takes email input. After submitting the form I am displaying a toast notification confirming the success or error of operation.

I created a Notification components which is rendered when ever my application state has the object of notification filled.

By submitting the form I am then dispatching an action which fills the notification object.
It works fine

But after dispatch the form loses its fields values

```
const {control, handleSubmit, setError, formState: {errors}, isSubmitting} = useForm({defaultValues: {email: ''}})
```

This is my form submit handler

```
const onSubmit = async data => {
    if (Object.values(data).every(field => field.length > 0)) {
       useJwt
         .forgotPassword({email: data.email})
         .then(res => dispatch(toastNotify({ status: "success", ...res.message })))
         .catch(({response}) => {
            if (response.status === 400 && response.data.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
               response.data.errors.forEach(error => setError(error['param'], {type: 'manual', message: error['msg']}))
            } else {
               // If I comment line below and log the response data, form values works fine
               dispatch(toastNotify({type: "error", ...response.data}))
            }
         })
    } else {
       for (const key in data) {
          if (data[key].length === 0) {
              setError(key, {
                 type: 'manual'
              })
          }
       }
    }
```

}

This is my form

```
<Form className='auth-forgot-password-form mt-2' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div className='mb-2'>
              <Label className='form-label' for='email'>
                Email
              </Label>
              <Controller
                id='email'
                name='email'
                control={control}
                render={({field}) => (
                  <Input type='text' id='email' name='email' autoFocus invalid={errors.email && true} {...field} />
                )}
              />
              {errors && errors.email && <FormFeedback>{ errors.email.message }</FormFeedback>}
            </div>
            <Button color='primary'  disabled={isSubmitting} block>
              {isSubmitting ? <Spinner size='sm' /> : 'Send reset link'}
            </Button>
          </Form>
```

Comment: Have you tried using e.preventDefault on submit ?

Comment: same here, any update? other than preventDefault that was not my issue